# Cufon javascript in Blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger, cufon

I'm trying to add a [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) font to a Blogger template. I've uploaded the cufon-yui.js and font.js to another server, and I reference them in the Blogger template in the head:

```
<script src="http://www.xyz.com/sukrin/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.xyz.com/sukrin/font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('body, h1, h2, h3, h5, p');
</script>
```

The font isn't appearing. I load the Blogger page, and look at the source, where the JS links are clickable -- when I click the link it takes me to the Google search page, not to the JS code (which I know is there -- if I put the link in the URL bar it appears).

Any ideas why this isn't working?

EDIT: This is now a different problem, sorry! All search results to that domain (i.e. if you search for www.xyz.com then click the result) redirects straight away to Google. No odd files in the server...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This has turned out to be caused by what I think must be some kind of hack, which causes a redirect when following any link to www.xyz.com.